# is it possible to split a suffix from a word without using any import

Tags: python

There are solutions to my problem with using regex.But isn't it possible to split the word 'intimation' to 'intima tion'
Isn't it possible to use such code not for splitting punctuations but for suffixes?

```
sentence = input()
punctuation = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~"
print( "".join([c if c not in punctuation else f' {c} ' for c in sentence]).strip().split() )
```

Comment: To answer your question, not it isnt. That code is iterating over singular characters

Comment: is the final thing that you want a single new string that is `'intima tion'`, that is just the original string with the blank space added in the middle? or do you want a list that contains the two strings `'intima'` and `'tion'`? Or just one of the single strings? I know the way you wrote the question is the single string with the space, but just want to confirm that.

Comment: @scotscotmcc Every time I see the suffix tion, I want it to be separated from the word.Not just for a word.(informa tion,affirma tion,emo tion etc.)

Comment: Have you tried ```string.rstrip(suf)``` where ```suf``` is ```tion``` and string is ```intimation```

Comment: @Sujay it works but I have more than one suffix so I am trying to do that for a list of suffixes not for a string and I do not know what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.partition(sep)`

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

```py
string = 'information and affirmation and emotion'
pattern = 'tion'
out = ''
par = string.partition(pattern)
while par[1]:  # pattern found?
    out += ' '.join([par[0], par[1]])
    par = par[2].partition(pattern)

print(out)
```

Result:
`informa tion and affirma tion and emo tion`

Edit - handling a list of patterns:

```py
string = 'information and affirmation and emotion, trying and failing.'
pattern_list = ['***', 'tion', 'ing']
for pattern in pattern_list:
    if pattern in string:
        out = ''
        par = string.partition(pattern)
        while par[1]:  # pattern found?
            out += ' '.join([par[0], par[1]])
            remainder = par[2]
            par = par[2].partition(pattern)
        string = ''.join([out, remainder])

print(''.join([out, remainder]))
```

Result:
`informa tion and affirma tion and emo tion, try ing and fail ing.`

Comment: Is it possible for the pattern to be list?

Comment: @0phase - here you are

Comment: thank youu, it made me look at it from another perspective!!! @ack

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of python (3.9, from Oct 2020) has a new `.removesuffix()` string method.

```py
suffix = 'tion'
word = 'intimation'
print(word.removesuffix(suffix))
```

This will return 'intima'.

I'm not positive how you want to integrate that into everything else you've got going on in your code, but that method will, as its name suggests, remove the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  `.rstrip()`

```
string="intimation"
suf="tion"
print("Original word: ",string)
print("After removing the suffix: ",string.rstrip(suf))

#== Output
Original word:  intimation
After removing the suffix:  intima
```

Comment: This might not (always) work as expected. E.g., `'teststring'.rstrip('string')` returns `'te'`, i.e., it removes individual characters.